# Java Sprint MVC JSON infinite recursion

Tags: java, json, hibernate, spring-mvc, recursion

Hi I have a very simple structure where I have following classes.
When making a select against List of users I am getting JSON infinite recursion.
I tried to put @JsonManagedReference and @JsonBackReference and all I got, was that I did not get JSON infinite recursion anymore, but if you look at image I uploaded you will see ugly response from server.

```
public class Organisations extends SuperModel implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id", nullable = true)
    private Organisations parent;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent")
    private List<Organisations> childs = new ArrayList<Organisations>(); }

public class Permissions extends SuperModel implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
    private Users user;

    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "organisation_id", nullable = false)
    private Organisations organisation;
}

public class Roles  extends SuperModel implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "organisation_id", nullable = false)
    private Organisations organisation;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 3, max = 20)
    @Column(name = "role", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String role;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name="role_permissions", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="role_id"), inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="permission_id"))
    private List<Permissions> permissions = new ArrayList<Permissions>();
}

public class Users extends SuperModel implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "organisation_id", nullable = false)
    private Organisations organisation;

    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @OneToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", nullable = false)
    private Roles role;
}
```

[This is an image from response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dlK32.png)

Comment: Never, ever, try to serialize a recursive data structure in json

Comment: It seems improper design of classes. You  have to much redundant relations. Remove `Users` field from `Permissions` or mark `Users` with `@JsonIgnore` annotation. In the latter case you will have to set this property manually.

Comment: Try to unproxy the entities to desired depth.

Comment: @KenBekov Image I have cloud system where I should know which organisation is the owner of any record, that's why I am using relations per table.

Answer (score 0):

@Javier you mean to remove implementation of serializable interface??? Do you think it will solve my problem??